# RegEx in PHP: match several links in one line of text

Tags: php, regex

I would like to match url with specific text from long line of text. But the problem is that there can be several links in that line. Sample text:

```
AAAAAA <a href="https://BBB.com">TEST1</a> CCC <a href="https://DDD.com/EEE-FFF/">GGGG</a> AAAAAA
```

And I would like to match link with "EEE-FFF" to delete this url later by preg_replace, so my goal is to get:

```
AAAAAA <a href="https://BBB.com">TEST1</a> CCC GGGG AAAAAA
```

I tried something like this:

```
/<a.*?EEE-FFF.*?>(.*?)<\/a>/U
```

But it match two links as a one. How can I fix it?

Comment: Remove the `U` flag. Replace `.*?` with `[^<>]*`

Comment: It doesn't change anything. The effect is the same.

Comment: Looks [perfectly working](https://regex101.com/r/r5Sefe/1) to me.

Comment: I checked before you edit first comment. Now it works perfecet - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$string = 'AAAAAA <a href="https://BBB.com">TEST1</a> CCC <a href="https://DDD.com/EEE-FFF/">GGGG</a> AAAAAA';
    $pattern = '/<a href="[^"]*EEE-FFF[^"]*">([^<]*)<\/a>/';
    $replacement = '$1';
    echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?>
```

Since you want to keep the contents within a matched pattern you want to match it to another group
https://regexr.com/6u5d5